# How to Resolve Drizzle ORM MySQL Relations Type Error

Tags: mysql, drizzle

I am trying to define a many to many relation ship between the employees and strengths tables.

I am getting  the error on the employeeStrengthRelations definition.

Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, Relation>'.
Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'any[]'.ts(2322)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  I want to query employees and get their strengths (title, not the id) in the query.

Here are the table definitions.

```
export const employees = mysqlTable('employees', {
  id: serial('id').notNull().primaryKey(),
  .....
});

export const strengths = mysqlTable('strengths', {
  id: serial('id').notNull().primaryKey(),
  title: varchar('title', { length: 255 }),
});

export const employee_strength = mysqlTable('employee_strength', {
  id: serial('id').notNull().primaryKey(),
  employee_id: bigint('employee_id', { mode: 'number' }).references(() => employees.id),
  strength_id: bigint('strength_id', { mode: 'number' }).references(() => strengths.id),
  order: int('order'),
});

export const employeeRelations = relations(employees, ({ many }) => ({
  employeesToStrengths: many(employee_strength),
}));

export const strengthsRelations = relations(strengths, ({ many }) => ({
  employeesToStrengths: many(employee_strength),
}));
```

This definition is the one giving the error

```
export const employeeStrengthRelations = relations(employee_strength, ({ one }) => ([
  strength: one(strengths, {
    fields: [employee_strength.strength_id],
    references: [strengths.id],
  }),
  employee: one(employees, {
    fields: [employee_strength.employee_id],
    references: [employees.id],
  }),
]));
```

Here is the query, in which I want to get the employees with an array of their strength.titles in order using the order column on employee_strength table.

```
const results = await this.db.query.employees.findMany({
      with: {
        employeesToStrengths: true,
      },
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax

```
export const employeeStrengthRelations = relations(
  employee_strength, ({ one }) => ({
    strength: one(strengths, {
      fields: [employee_strength.strength_id],
      references: [strengths.id],
    }),
    employee: one(employees, {
      fields: [employee_strength.employee_id],
      references: [employees.id],
    }),
  }),
);
```

Thank you Angelelz!